# Salesforce Send - Report - question on import behaviour?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

I have created a **Salesforce Send** which use a **Report** in Sales cloud.
My report in Sales cloud gets updated weekly!
If I use this SalesforceSend in my automation, which is set to run Weekly and send emails.
Will the updated Report will be picked every week? or I need to Run report/re-select the Report by editing SalesforceSend every week?
Will the Report run at the time when Marketing cloud tries to send the email?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to verify this and confirm that WE NEED NOT MAKE ANY CHANGES, once we create the Salesforce send, IF we are using the **REPORT** from Sales cloud. 
 And the Automation will aways pick the latest/updated REPORT when Runs every time.
[image]

#### Note: This DOES NOT hold good, if you using the IMPORT to bring in your Report to Salesforce Data Extension.